# Dependency injection from service to another service not working symfony 5

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony5

I am trying to configure dependency injection for a "Newuser" service. In order not to depend on mysql in the future, what is done is to create a "mysqlService" service that implements an interface with the "persist" method.

From the controller I instantiate the use case "NewUser" that in its constructor by injecting the interface of "DatabaseServiceInterface" and another service "UserPasswordEncoderInterface".

It doesn't work properly since symfony complains because "NewUser doesn't receive anything as parameter" (When the service should be automatically injected).

Files are:

DatabaseServiceInterface:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService;



 Interface DatabaseServiceInterface
 {
   public function persist(Object $ormObject):void;
 }
```

MysqlService:

```
<?php

namespace App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;


class MysqlService implements DatabaseServiceInterface
{
   private $entityManager;

   public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
   {
      $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
   }

   public function persist(Object $ormObject):void{
      $this->entityManager->persist($ormObject);
      $this->entityManager->flush();
   }

 }
```

RegistrationController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser\NewUserRequest;
use App\Application\Domain\User\User;
use App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\
DatabaseServiceInterface;
use App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\MysqlService;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Application\Infraestructure\User\UserAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\
UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;
use App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser\NewUser;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
  {
   /**
   * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
   */
  public function register(Request $request, 
  UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, 
  GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler, UserAuthenticator 
  $authenticator): Response
  {
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $newUserRequest = new NewUserRequest();
        $newUserRequest->email = $form->get('email')->getData();
        $newUserRequest->user = $user;
        $newUserRequest->password = $form->get('plainPassword')- 
        >getData();

        $newUser = new NewUser();
        $newUser->execute($newUserRequest);


        // do anything else you need here, like send an email

        return $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
            $user,
            $request,
            $authenticator,
            'main' // firewall name in security.yaml
        );
    }

    return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
        'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
   }
 }
```

Usecas NewUser

```
<?php

namespace App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser;

use App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\
DatabaseServiceInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\
UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class NewUser {

private $databaseService;
private $passwordEncoder;

public function __construct(
    DatabaseServiceInterface $databaseService,
    UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
) {
    $this->databaseService = $databaseService;
    $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
}

public function execute(NewUserRequest $userRegisterRequest) {

    //Encode the plain password
    $userRegisterRequest->user->setPassword(
        $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
            $userRegisterRequest->user,
            $userRegisterRequest->password
        )
    );

    $userRegisterRequest->user->setEmail($userRegisterRequest->email);
    $userRegisterRequest->user->setRoles(array_unique(['ROLE_USER']));

    //crear servicio para mysql
    $this->databaseService->persist($userRegisterRequest->user);

  }

  }
```

Services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where 
the app is deployed
#https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/
configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
  locale: en
  availableLocales:
        - es


services:
   # default configuration for services in *this* file
   _defaults:
      autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your 
services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as 
    commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified 
class name
   App\:
       resource: '../src/*'
       exclude: 
      '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,
      Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

# controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
# as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller 
#class

App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService\
DatabaseServiceInterface: 
App\Application\Infraestructure\DatabaseService
```

Although symfony does not throw any errors because it seems that the configuration is fine it still does not work. The error it throws when executing the use case is the following:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Application\AppUseCases\User\NewUser\NewUser::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/symfony/src/Controller/RegistrationController.php on line 33 and exactly 2 expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not retrieving the `NewUser` class from the container, but instancing it manually, so Dependency Resolution is not happening and the service is not reciving any of its dependencies. You should inject the service into the controller for dependency resolution to occur, or pass the arguments explicitly when instancing it.

```
public function register(Request $request, 
  UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, 
  GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler, 
  UserAuthenticator $authenticator, 
  NewUser $newUser): Response
{
       //...
       $newUserRequest = new NewUserRequest();
       //...
       // $newUser = new NewUser();   // Not passing The Database or PasswordEncoder dep           
       $newUser->execute($newUserRequest);
       //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! now its working. But i have a question. It is possible that symfony inject automatically when you instanciate class without passing parameters explicity?

Comment: @AlbertSanchezGuerrero Not by using the `new` keyword. You could do it through the container, but that's  discouraged (`$this->container->get(NewUser::class)`).

Comment: thanks for the comment. I saw in many sites how in DDD are using instanciate usecase for tis purpose. I spend many time for trying to instanciate this usecase on controller and so, another time. Thanks!